# How to get feature from PostGIS to OpenLayers with ASP.NET?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, asp.net

[image]

I need to show my feature from this table in PostGIS in my ASP.NET web page web.

Has anyone done that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit out of date, but this workshop shows the basic concept (using JSTL, not ASP though).

http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-spatialdbtips/

Answer (score 0):

For example : You can use an ORM Postgresql .net